# How to add names to your GraphQL queries and mutations in GraphiQL?

Tags: graphql, graphiql

What is the syntax for naming your GraphQL queries and mutations specifically from the GraphiQL GUI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34011964/6124657

Comment: Thanks for posting that link. It does provide an explanation as to the purpose of named queries. I am editing the question to specifically ask how to add names to queries/mutations in graphiql.

Comment: contains sytax examples and some explanations?

Comment: Yup, you are right. I was thinking I leave the question/and my answer to provide new graphqlers a reference for when they google the same thing. What do you think about that?

Comment: sure, you can ... not very usable option (IMHO very rarely) ... as usually only one query/mutation tested at the same time ... name is almost always required for mutations (usually requires variables definition) - name added for other/more important reasons then playground usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add names to graphiql queries, simply add the name you want after the root type, as seen below. You will then have the option to run the query by name when you click the play button.

```
query query_one {
#some query in here
}
mutation mutation_one {
#some mutation in here
}
```

[image]