# Does Gatsby cache graphQL queries by Operation Name?

Tags: caching, graphql, gatsby

I've read this question which is more general: [What is the point of naming queries and mutations in GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011964/what-is-the-point-of-naming-queries-and-mutations-in-graphql). The top answer indicates that Operation Name is meaningless, but a particular implementation *can* give it meaning.

My team lead and I are working refactoring some data into new static queries which might be repeated many times across the app. We *think* that naming the queries will allow Gatsby to cache the results, which would be great. But I can't actually find anything saying that in the Gatsby docs and now neither of us know where that idea came from. All I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011964/what-is-the-point-of-naming-queries-and-mutations-in-graphql) rather unhelpful description. So, does giving these queries names actually help us here, or is it pointless?

Answer (score 0):

The operation name is irrelevant as Gatsby generates its own unique name internally (you can add it so that it makes it into that generation). If you e.g. create a custom hook with a `useStaticQuery` and then use that throughout your app, it'll only use that (so it's "cached").